# How can I automate the replacing of AWS Launch Template AMIs with AMIs made with Packer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, packer

I am using Packer to build custom AMIs in AWS. Is there a way to automate the process of building new images weekly to replace the current AMIs in my launch templates?

I am currently using in the launch templates AWS-owned AMIs and scripts in userdata to provision the packages and code required for each instance. The idea is to replace userdata script by a fresh custom AMI.

So far I managed to setup Packer to build the images, I am planning to use Jenkins to weekly build new images. But I can´t figure out how I should replace the AMIs in the Launch  Templates. Any ideas?

Comment: "automating the process of building new images" and "automate the replacing of AMIs in launch templates" are two different questions. Which are you asking?

Comment: I'm asking how to automate the replacing of AMIs in launch templates.